# Scraping a simple html table returns u'\n (Python with BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table using [this](http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/10/beginner-guide-web-scraping-beautiful-soup-python/) tutorial. I'm fairly sure I am getting the right table, but my output is just lists full of `u'\n'`.

The line `if len(cells) == 10:` is supposed to let me only scrape the actual contents, not the header; if I change the number, all of my lists return as `None`, but with the number `10` they are filled with the correct number of entries, it's just that those entries are all the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jun 29 13:21:36 2016

@author: natasha
"""
import urllib2

ukr = "http://www.ukrstat.gov.ua/operativ/operativ2013/rp/zn_ed_reg/zn_ed_reg_e/zn_ed_reg_2014k_e.htm"

page = urllib2.urlopen(ukr)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

#scraping just the first table
table = soup.find('table', id = "table2")

#creating lists for future variables

NAM=[]
TOT=[]
AGR=[]
IND=[]
CON=[]
TRA=[]
STO=[]
ACC=[]
INF=[]
FIN=[]

#looping over rows

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    if len(cells) == 10:
        NAM.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        TOT.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        AGR.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        IND.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
        CON.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
        TRA.append(cells[5].find(text=True))
        STO.append(cells[6].find(text=True))
        ACC.append(cells[7].find(text=True))
        INF.append(cells[8].find(text=True))
        FIN.append(cells[9].find(text=True))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this is the behavior you get, but you sure do not need to call `find()` in each cell. You can get the content of the cell from its `text` attribute. If you replace

```
    NAM.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
```

with

```
    NAM.append(cells[0].text)
```

this will be the value of `NAM`:

```
[u'\n\r\n\t\tUkraine', u'\n\r\n\t\tVinnytsia',
 u'\nVolyn', u'\n\r\n\t\tDnipropetrovsk', u'\nDonetsk',
 u'\n\r\n\t\tZhytomyr', u'\n\r\n\t\tTranscarpathean',
 u'\n\r\n\t\tZaporizhia', ...]
```

(Of course, there is a lot of `\r`, `\n`, `\t` etch that one does not need. We can remove them by calling the `strip()` string method:

```
    NAM.append(cells[0].text.strip())
```

Here is the result:

```
[u'Ukraine', u'Vinnytsia', u'Volyn', u'Dnipropetrovsk', u'Donetsk',
 u'Zhytomyr', u'Transcarpathean', u'Zaporizhia', u'Ivano-Frankivsk',
 u'Kyiv', u'Kirovohrad', u'Luhansk', u'Lviv', u'Mykolaiv', u'Odesa',
 u'Poltava', u'Rivne', u'Sumy', u'Ternopil', u'Kharkiv', u'Kherson',
 u'Khmelnytsk', u'Cherkasy', u'Chernivtsi', u'Chernihiv',
 u'City of \r\n\t\tKyiv']
```